# torsion-free and divisible

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a domain with fraction field $Q$.
If $A$ is a torsion-free $R$-module, then there is an exact sequence

$$0 \to A \to V \to T \to 0$$

where $V$ is a vector space over $Q$ and $T$ is torsion.

Proof. Let $V = Env(A)$, the injective envelope of $A$. If $v \in V$, then there is $r \in R$ with $rv \neq 0$ and $rv \in A$. It follows that $A$ torsion-free implies $V$ torsion-free and that $V/A$ is torsion. Finally, $V$ is a vector space over $Q$ as it is torsion-free and divisible.

I am a bit confused:

1. why is this: If $v \in V$, then there is $r \in R$ with $rv \neq 0$ and $rv \in A$. I am not sure if it's because I'm not aware of some properties of injective envelopes?
2. why is $V$ divisible?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is $Q$ supposed to be $\mathbb{Q}$ or is it any field, that you choose to name $Q$?

Comment: Q is a fraction field of the domain R. It doesn't have to be the rationals. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question you need to know two things about injective modules:

- any injective module over an integral ring is divisible;
- the injective hull of a module is an essential extension of that module, meaning that (with your notation) if $M\subset V$ is any submodule, then either $M=0$ or $M\cap A\neq \{0\}$.

The second property answers your first question by taking $M=Rv$.

To prove the first property, take $v\in V$ and $r\in R$, and apply the injective property to extend the morphism $R\to V$ sending $1$ to $v$ along the injective morphism $R\to R$ given by multiplication by $r$. The fact that the morphism extends shows that $v$ is $r$-divisible.

Comment: many thx! all clear now! it was me being silly!